# pattern match failing when looking for characters inside quotes

Tags: mysql, regex, replace

I have this staring in my column data in MySQL DB:

```
<sxyz lang="en" class="multilang">Encyclopedia</sxyz>
```

I need to make it like

```
Encyclopedia</sxyz>
```

chopping off the first part.  Now I can have spaces in between and I want to account for that.

assuming myfielddata is the string above....

I've tried:

```
select replace(myfielddata,'<sxyz[[:space:]]+lang="[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+"[[:space:]]+class="multilang">','')   from mytable
```

and it does not work.

I've event paired this down to bare minimum to match the "en" only like

```
select replace(myfielddata,'<sxyz lang="[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+" class="multilang">','')   from mytable
```

It still doesn't work.

The only thing that works if I do an exact match of the string

```
select replace(myfielddata,'<sxyz lang="en" class="multilang">','')   from mytable
```

but that just doesn't taking into account any extra spaces that might appear in between.

Help please you RegEx gurus.

A.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL doesn't have any regular expression based replacement functions, [only regular expression based matching](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html), in particular, [`replace`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) only does literal string replacement.

You'll have to do it the hard way with [`locate`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) and [`substr`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_substr) (or something similar):

```
mysql> select substr('<sxyz lang="en" class="multilang">Encyclopedia</sxyz>' from locate('>', '<sxyz lang="en" class="multilang">Encyclopedia</sxyz>') + 1) as truncated;
+---------------------+
| truncated           |
+---------------------+
| Encyclopedia</sxyz> |
+---------------------+
```

You will of course want to make sure your strings match the desired pattern before you put them through the above string mangler and you can use a regex for that.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
select replace(myfielddata,'<sxyz.*"multilang">','')
```

or

```
select replace(myfielddata,'^<sxyz.*"multilang">$','')
```